# WCF - DataContract that inherits from an interface

Tags: wcf, interface, datacontract

I have a datacontract as part of my WCF Interface that inherits from IIdentity:

```
 [DataContract]
 public class AuthenticationIdentity : IIdentity
 {
    //implements IIdentity...
 }
```

The service returns my AuthenticationIdentity objects just fine. However, when I try and do the obvious cast on the client:

```
AuthenticationIdentity aId = client.GetID();
IIdentity id = aId;
```

I get a complaint that AuthenticationIdentity cannot be cast to IIdentity. I've tried adding the ServiceKnownTypes to the interface:

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(AuthenticationIdentity))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(IIdentity))]
```

but still no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you control both sides of the wire (which it looks like you do since you want to cast to `IIdentity`), you can reference your `DataContract` from a shared assembly.  Then you can use [svcutil to share the DataContracts](https://web.archive.org/web/20120104101823/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/cicorias/archive/2006/12/31/102393.aspx) between the service and the consumer.  Or, if you wanted to cut out svcutil altogether, you could write your own proxy to use the shared assembly.